# How to check if a given data exists in multiple tables (all of which has the same column)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, each consisting of a column called username. On the registration part, I need to check that the requested username is new and unique.

I need that single SQL that will tell me if that user exists in any of these tables, before I proceed. I tried:

```
SELECT tbl1.username, tbl2.username, tbl3.username
FROM tbl1,tbl2,tbl3
WHERE tbl1.username = {$username}
   OR tbl2.username = {$username}
   OR tbl3.username ={$username}
```

Is that the way to go?

Comment: you have three tables with the same column?? I assume you do know about normalisation, and this is intentional?

Comment: I am a complete noob to db programming :)

Comment: then I suggest you go back to your db design after reading about normalisation up to 3NF. Something like a username should only be stored once and associated with an ID, then referenced by other tables via foreign keys. Then your current problem, and presumably many others in the future, would be much simpler. Also you should think about what it means if the username exists in >0 but <3 of your tables - and how you would know when you perform your query.

Comment: @Brian Patterson a little harsh, no? I've never met a single developer who doesn't "learn on the job". Granted the poster is at the far end of the spectrum, but having a go at someone isn't the best way to encourage improvement

Comment: I'll have to comment that. The username that I have resting in the other two tables are supposed to be users that reserve their place. It's like an invitation, that once confirmed, will be deployed into the db. This is why I have USERNAME in more than one table. I am noob to db programming but I have good programming skills. I'll have to look up for normalization and why is it bad to have the same name for the USERNAME in three tables.

Comment: can you tell us why there are 3 different tables with usernames ?

Comment: Relax, Brian.  Though everyone starts as a noob, there's no requirement to end up as a jerk.  Answer his question, gently guide him to better design.  And for a reality check, anyone whose architected an EII solution has had to deal with this exact problem, so while @Ted might be green to DB normalization, his problem comes up often in large integrations.

Comment: @Ted: create the invitation as a normal user record, but add a Confirmed flag to the table. Periodically, you can delete records that are not Confirmed that are more than X days old, to free up those usernames for others to use.

Comment: Hey @RedFilter, I think this is correct. I should have done it this way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
select 1 
from (
    select username as username from tbl1
    union all
    select username from tbl2
    union all
    select username from tbl3
) a
where username = 'someuser'
```

Comment: Nice 'give a man a fish answer', but this does not solve underlying issues.

Comment: Hi RedFilter, This gives me an error I run this inside phpMyAdmin, could you please check? Thanks

Comment: nope, it says "Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'"

Comment: It sounds like the collation is not the same on each of the username columns.

Comment: You are correct. I had utf8_unicode_ci instead of utf8_general_ci, Thanks !

Comment: Great. It helped me a lot. Thank You !

Answer (score 19):

**In the event you honestly just want to know if a user exists:**

The quickest approach is an existence query:

```
select 
NOT EXISTS (select username from a where username = {$username}) AND 
NOT EXISTS (select username from b where username = {$username}) AND 
NOT EXISTS (select username from c where username = {$username});
```

If your `username` column is marked as `Unique` in each table, this should be the most efficient query you will be able to make to perform this operation, and this *will outperform a normalized username table* in terms of memory usage and, well, virtually *any* other query that cares about `username` and another column, as there are no excessive joins.  If you've ever been called on to speed up an organization's database, I can assure you that over-normalization is a nightmare.  In regards to the advice you've received on normalization in this thread, be wary.  It's great for limiting space, or limiting the number of places you have to update data, but you have to weigh that against the maintenance and speed overhead.  Take the advice given to you on this page with a grain of salt.

Get used to running a query analyzer on your queries, if for no other reason than to get in the habit of learning the ramifications of choices when writing queries -- at least until you get your sea legs.

**In the event you want to insert a user later:**

If you are doing this for the purpose of eventually adding the user to the database, here is a better approach, and it's worth it to learn it.  Attempt to insert the value immediately.  Check afterwards to see if it was successful.  This way there is no room for some other database call to insert a record in between the time you've checked and the time you inserted into the database.  For instance, in MySQL you might do this:

```
INSERT INTO {$table} (`username`, ... )
  SELECT {$username} as `username`, ... FROM DUAL 
   WHERE 
     NOT EXISTS (select username from a where username = {$username}) AND 
     NOT EXISTS (select username from b where username = {$username}) AND 
     NOT EXISTS (select username from c where username = {$username});
```

All database API's I've seen, as well as all SQL implementations will provide you a way to discover how many rows were inserted.  If it's 1, then the username didn't exist and the insertion was successful.  In this case, I don't know your dialect, and so I've chosen MySQL, which provides a `DUAL` table specifically for returning results that aren't bound to a table, but honestly, there are many ways to skin this cat, whether you put it in a transaction or a stored procedure, or strictly limit the process and procedure that can access these tables.

**Update -- How to handle users who don't complete the sign up process**

As @RedFilter points out, if registration is done in multiple steps -- reserving a username, filling out details, perhaps answering an email confirmation, then you will want to at least add a column to flag this user (with a timestamp, not a boolean) so that you can periodically remove users after some time period, though I recommend creating a `ToBePurged` table and add new users to that, along with a timestamp.  When the confirmation comes through, you remove the user from this table.  Periodically you will check this table for all entries prior to some delta off your current time and simply delete them from whichever table they were originally added.  My philosophy behind this is to define more clearly the responsibility of the table and to keep the number of records you are working with very lean.  We certainly don't want to over-engineer our solutions, but if you get into the habit of good architectural practices, these designs will flow out as naturally as their less efficient counterparts.

Comment: Are the (inner) joins not going to filter out usernames in tables 'b' and 'c', if they don't have corresponding rows in 'a'? (presumably not all usernames are in 'a', 'b' and 'c', otherwise there would be no real need to check for existence in all of the tables)

Comment: Using the inner join will only return a row if the username exists in all three tables.  This doesn't seem like what the OP wants.  If the name only appears in one of the tables, the inner join will always be empty, so you'll need to make three independent existence checks.  However, I did make an error in my insertion query, which for some reason, did use inner joins.  I've subsequently fixed the query, so if you are referring to that, then my bad, good catch -- I meant to cut and paste the existence checks from the first query.

Comment: Yes, I was just referring to your 'insert' statement, which as you stated is now corrected; my apologies for not making that clearer originally - When it came to clarity, it didn't help that I missed "and vice-versa" from the rhetorical question in my comment! :)

Answer (score 2):

No.  Two processes could run your test at the same time and both would report no user and then both could insert the same user.

It sounds like you need a single table to hold ALL the users with a unique index to prevent duplicates.  This master table could link to 'sub-tables' using a user ID, not user name.

Answer (score 2):

Given the collation stuff, you could do this instead, if you don't want to deal with the collation mismatch:

```
select sum(usercount) as usercount
from (
    select count(*) as usercount from tbl1 where username = 'someuser'
    union all
    select count(*) as usercount from tbl2 where username = 'someuser'
    union all
    select count(*) as usercount from tbl3 where username = 'someuser'
) as usercounts
```

If you get 0, there isn't a user with that username, if you get something higher, there is.

Note: Depending on how you do the insert, you could in theory get more than one user with the same username due to race conditions (see other comments about normalisation and unique keys).

Answer (score 1):

1- You need to normalize your tables

See: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

2- Don't use implicit SQL '89 joins.

Kick the habit and use explicit joins

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field2, c.field3
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.a_id)  -- JOIN criteria go here
INNER JOIN c ON (b.id = c.b_id)  -- and here, nice and explicit.
WHERE ... -- filter criteria go here.
```

Comment: But inner joins are supposed to match aren't they ? I need to check if the value exists in one of them. it should be on only one if at all

Comment: Inner joins **do not need to match** although they usually do.

Comment: @ted, Anyway first you need to normalize, only after that do the joins become relevant.

Comment: He should not normalize these tables at all unless there is a huge overlap between the tables aside from the username itself.

Answer (score 0):

With your current set up RedFilter's answer should work fine. I thought it would be worth noting that you shouldn't have redundant or dispersed data in your database to begin with though.

You should have one and only one place to store any specific data - so in your case, instead of having a username in 3 different tables, you should have one table with username and a primary key identifier for those usernames.  Your other 3 tables should then foreign-key reference the username table. You'll be able to construct much simpler and more efficient queries with this layout.  You're opening a can of worms by replicating data in various locations.