# Check if email is in either of two tables

Tags: php, sql

I want to check if the email entered in a form belongs to either of two tables: Clients and Students. If it exists in either, then I want to stop the process. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the following code:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sqlCheckEmail = " SELECT *
                   FROM students AS a
                   INNER JOIN clients AS b
                   ON a.Email = b.Email
                   WHERE a.Email = '$email' ";
$queryCheckEmail = $connection->query($sqlCheckEmail);
$rowExists = mysqli_num_rows($queryCheckEmail);
if( $rowExists > "0" ){
    echo "<h1>Error: Email already exists in database! <br> Redirecting......</h1>";
    header('Refresh: 2;url=../pages/register.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `JOIN` with a condition that looks for matching emails in both tables. You need to use a [**`UNION`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
$sqlCheckEmail = "(SELECT *
                   FROM students
                   WHERE Email = '$email')
                   UNION
                  (SELECT *
                   FROM clients
                   WHERE Email = '$email')";
```

Obviously, you may need to tweak the above if your columns don't match up perfectly (you need the same number of columns in both `SELECT` statements and, if you want the results to make sense, you want them to be the same types of data).

**NOTE:** You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, not direct evaluation of variables like `$email`. This is especially (but not only) true when you get the data from the user, as you do with `$email = $_POST['email'];`.

One more thought: `$rowExists > "0"` may work, but it doesn't really make sense. `$rowExists` will be an integer. Compare it to `0`, not `"0"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. However, how would I "echo" out which table it exists in? eg. If the email exists in the "students" database, how would I print a statement like: "Error: email exists in STUDENTS database"?

Comment: Add a column, like `(SELECT "Students" AS source_table, students.* FROM ... ) UNION (SELECT "Clients" AS source_table, clients.* FROM ...)`

Answer (score 0):

If your asking about the query, how about this

```
Select *
From (
 select Email from students
 UNION 
 select Email from clients
 )
WHERE Email = '$email';
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232704/how-to-check-if-a-given-data-exists-in-multiple-tables-all-of-which-has-the-sam) that might be more for what you're asking. I don't see any UPPER() casing either. Might need to consider that when dealing with client values.

I agree with the SQL injection. Check for that.