# I have two different type of user table and I want to check mobile duplication in single query in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

There is few more class variable in both class, but I removed them. I tried union query but it didn't work. Is there any other way to perform this operation in single query.

Here is my union query:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select vu.mobileNumber AS mn from VillageUser vu where vu.mobileNumber = :inmobile UNION select ca.mobileNumber AS mn from CustomerAccount ca where ca.mobileNumber = :inmobile");
```

Here is my table:

```
public class VillageUser extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ASSEMBLY_USER_ID")
    private Long auAccountId;

    @Column(name="FULL_NAME")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="USER_TYPE")
    private String userType;

    @Column(name="MOBILE_NUMBER")
    private String mobileNumber;
}

public class AssamblyUser extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="FULL_NAME")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="USER_TYPE")
    private String userType;

    @Column(name="MOBILE_NUMBER")
    private String mobileNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unions are not supported by HQL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7182537/3076981).

However you can create a SQL using Union and use this in hibernate

```
session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).addScalar("mobileNumber",StringType.INSTANCE)
```

Comment: i m using entity manager to perform this operation and somehow i didn't get the session to create sql query. i tried also a native query which return cartesian product but it not work if any of table is empty. does any other way to check it?

Comment: i know that i can use query for each table then put both query result in a single list then check list. but i don't want to hit database two time for each table.

Comment: can you post native query?

Comment: you can check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232704/how-to-check-if-a-given-data-exists-in-multiple-tables-all-of-which-has-the-sam) for help in query.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the perfect way to perform this.

use entitymanager.createNativeQuery() like below:

String mobilenumber = "1212121212";

String querystring = "select 1 from (select MOBILE_NUMBER as mobile from VILLAGE_USER union all select MOBILE_NUMBER as mobile from CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT) a where mobile ="+mobilenumber;

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(querystring);

List mobile = query.getResultList();